# how to run a python selenium celery task as asnyc task when celery is up and ready to work in Windows?

Tags: python, django, windows, celery, celerybeat

I need to run a celery task when the Celery is started (at start up) and it's ready to work in a Django environment.

I have more than 5 celery tasks and those are running parallel without problem. but when i call Selenium task below, other tasks are paused and after Selenium task is done, other 5 tasks continue their work.

selenium task must works as async forever in a `While True: ...` block code and this task tries to login to a website and do something on logged-in account.

the selenium task should not have `pause` impact on other tasks are running.

this selenium task just should be called one time. itself has `While True:...` loop code.

**celery.py:**

```
import os, redis
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

celery_app = Celery('ea_games')
celery_app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
celery_app.control.discard_all()
celery_app.control.purge()
celery_app.autodiscover_tasks()
BASE_REDIS_URL = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')
celery_app.conf.broker_url = BASE_REDIS_URL
celery_app.control.discard_all()
celery_app.control.purge()
```

**tasks.py:**

````
## when Celery is launched and it's ready to work, it will run the ```task_get_selenium_token``` task.
@worker_ready.connect
def at_start (sender, *args, **kwargs):
    with sender.app.connection() as conn:
        sender.app.send_task("ea_app.tasks.task_get_selenium_token", args, connection=conn)

@celery_app.task
def task_get_selenium_token():
    get_token()   ## this python function works permanently in a ```While True:...``` code.
````

**Note:** i tried to do it with `celery-beat`. but when celery-beat daemon is launched in windows terminal, it send the scheduled task to Celery; and when celery is launched it will run all unacknowledged tasks.

terminal 1:

> celery -A ea_games worker -l info --pool=eventlet --concurrency=200

new update/edit (even code below cant to work parallel with other tasks. when the selenium is launched, other tasks wait for it to finish its work. ://// how to fix problem?):

```
celery_app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'get-token-every-100-sec': {
        'task': 'ea_app.tasks.task_get_token',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=100),
    },
}

@celery_app.task
def task_get_token():
    get_token()
    return "Done..."
```